# Where is the retain count stored for NSObjects in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I am curious about how retain/release work internally.  On the face, it seems like there's an integer related to each instance of an `NSObject`, which gets increased and decreased when you call `-retain` and `-release`, respectively.

But taking a look at `NSObject`, the only instance variable it has is the `isa` variable, for determining its class type.

So where are retain counts for individual objects stored?  Not that I'm going to muck around with it, but just for my own edification.

Is it stored with the `NSObject`, but hidden away in some Objective C implementation detail?  If so, that seems like a bad design to me.  One *should* be able to create their own root class and handle their own retain/release counting in a similar fashion (not that it's a good idea--one would have to have a *very* good reason not to use `NSObject`).

Comment: http://whentouseretaincount.com/

Comment: When we talk about objects, she should ideally talk about [black boxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box), meaning we should not care about the implementations details but about the interfaces.  
You propose, that Apple should give us the details of retain counting, but I say with the interface definition we have just the right amount of data we would need to recreate it. We kown we have to implement `-retain`, `-release`, `-dealloc`,… to recreate NSObjetcs memory management — but we are free to do it who ever it seems best for us.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The storage location for the retain count depends on both the runtime in use and the class implementation.

For Apple's Objective-C runtime, you can figure out a lot by digging into [the source code of the Objective-C runtime](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.11/).

For example, if you're using ARC (and I think even if you're not), the reference counts for most objects are stored in hash tables.  Have a look at the `_objc_rootRetain` function in `runtime/objc-arr.mm`.  I don't know exactly why they did this.  Perhaps it's a way of keeping retain counts together for better cache behavior (which is important under ARC because ARC adjusts retain counts more often than non-ARC code usually does).

However, some classes override `retain` and related methods and store the retain count elsewhere.  For example, when debugging a memory leak I discovered that `CALayer` does this.  Instead of using the runtime's normal retain count mechanism, a `CALayer` stores its retain count in a private C++ implementation object.  This is rather frustrating because it means the Instruments Allocations instrument doesn't log retains and releases of `CALayer` objects.

Comment: To add to this - one possible reason is that the NSConstantString class must have a very specific layout (see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Constant-string-objects.html)) which does not include a retainCount ivar. As NSConstantString is a subclass of NSString, which is a subclass of NSObject, this means that if they gave NSObject an extra ivar, they would have to build the NSConstantString class from scratch, essentially from another base class. This is just one reason, I'm sure there are other (better) ones.

Comment: @PLPiper Actually, `__NSCFConstantString` simply overrides `retain`, `release`, and `autorelease` as no-ops.  Try `disass -n '-[__NSCFConstantString retain]'` in the debugger.  It also overrides `retainCount` to return `~0` (on 32-bit) or `~0UL >> 4` (on 64-bit), and it has a flag bit set that tells `CFGetRetainCount` to return one of those values.

Answer (score 7):

We do not know exactly how the data is stored, but we can rule out a few options:

## Private Implementation Variables

We can rule this out, simply because when we iterate through the iVars of the `NSObject` class, we see only one: `isa`, as shown through this program:

```
id object = [NSObject new];
Class meta = object->isa;

printf("class name: %s\n", class_getName(meta));

unsigned count;
Ivar *ivars = class_copyIvarList(meta, &count);

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    printf("iVar: %s\n", ivar_getName(ivars[i]));
}

free(ivars);
```

And note that even private implementation properties exist in the class metdata.

## Private Properties

We can also rule this out, as even private properties are exposed in the classes metadata, as shown by the following example, there are no properties for the `NSObject` class:

```
id object = [NSObject new];    
Class meta = object->isa;

printf("class name: %s\n", class_getName(meta));

objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(meta, &count);

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    printf("property: %s\n", property_getName(properties[i]));
}
```

## Associated Objects

This one is very hard to rule out, as there are no direct ways to get a list of all the associated objects. However, since the concept of associated objects is very new, and reference counting has been around forever, I say that this is not very likely.

## CoreFoundation struct-mangling

This is my best guess. When you create a NSObject, it is a struct behind the scenes. What is to say that the actual NSObject data representation is something like this:

```
typedef struct CFObject {
    int retainCount;
    id isa;
} *CFObjectRef;
```

Then, when an object is created:

```
id object_createInstance(...)
{
    CFObjectRef object = malloc(sizeof(struct CFObject));

    ...

    return (id) (object + sizeof(object->retainCount));
}

int object_retainCount(id self)
{
    CFObjectRef asObject = (CFObjectRef) (self - sizeof(asObject->retainCount));
    return asObject->retainCount;
}
```

I cannot verify this however, as there are many other ways this could be done (a map of integers to objects, for example).

Comment: Excellent answer which is also useful for other things!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound like it, but just in case... if you're thinking of using retain count directly, [don't](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2011/12/18/retaincount-is-useless/).

As for implementation details, sessions at WWDC 2011 mentioned that under ARC, most of the reference counting implementation has moved into the ObjC runtime. [Source for that is available](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.9/), so you might be able to find out for yourself how it works. For manual reference counting, much of the ObjC behaviors are replicated in CoreFoundation and libdispatch, which are also open source -- if you're looking to implement a similar scheme yourself, those might prove educational.

In general, this is an implementation detail for the same reason many things are: encapsulation is good policy, especially for framework providers. You don't want users of a framework depending on implementation details because then you can't change your implementation without breaking their code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this would be relevant, but I've stumbled upon the [blog post](http://jpobjc.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/my-higher-order-message-implementation/) about higher order messages implementation in the Objective-C. There author implements the HOM object as a root class (i.e. not inherited from NSObject) and the implementation looks like this:

```
@interface HigherOrderMessage {
    Class isa;
    NSUInteger retainCount;

    //not relevant to this question part
}
```

Then the retain count managing methods are implemented like this:

```
- (id)retain {
    __sync_add_and_fetch(&retainCount, 1);
    return self;
}

- (id)autorelease {
    [NSAutoreleasePool addObject:self];
    return self;
}

- (void)release {
    if (__sync_sub_and_fetch(&retainCount, 1) == 0) {
        [methodSignatureForSelector release];
        [forward release];
        object_dispose(self);
    }
}
```

This code actually works, so although we do not know how exactly the retainCount is implemented in the Cocoa classes, it is certain that it *could* be implemented in some similar way.

Answer (score 0):

For addition insight, check out http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-16-lets-build-reference-counting.html, where Mike Ash explores an alternative implementation like the one Apple uses.